# Callout I click on Map and appears ViewController2

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I cannot see the second entry in the `Map` and take me to `DetailViewController2`.

Is there any way to fix this?

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController2.h"

#import "SFAnnotation.h"            // annotation for the city of San Francisco
#import "BridgeAnnotation.h"        // annotation for the Golden Gate bridge
#import "CustomAnnotation.h"        // annotation for the Tea Garden

@interface MapViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mapAnnotations;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *bridgePopoverController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *sfPopoverController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *customPopoverController;

@end


#pragma mark -

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)gotoDefaultLocation
{
    // EMPEZAR CON UNA LOCALIZACIÓN DETERMINADA
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = 41.651981;
    newRegion.center.longitude = -4.728561;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1;
     self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // restore the nav bar to translucent
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create a custom navigation bar button and set it to always says "Back"
    UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    temporaryBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;

    // create out annotations array (in this example only 3)
    self.mapAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    // annotation for the City of San Francisco
    SFAnnotation *sfAnnotation = [[SFAnnotation alloc] init];
    [self.mapAnnotations addObject:sfAnnotation];

    // annotation for Golden Gate Bridge
    BridgeAnnotation *bridgeAnnotation = [[BridgeAnnotation alloc] init];
    [self.mapAnnotations addObject:bridgeAnnotation];


    // annotation for Tea Garden
    CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
    [self.mapAnnotations addObject:customAnnotation];




    [self allAction:self];  // initially show all annotations
}


#pragma mark - Button Actions

- (void)gotoByAnnotationClass:(Class)annotationClass
{
    // user tapped "City" button in the bottom toolbar
    for (id annotation in self.mapAnnotations)
    {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:annotationClass])
        {
            // remove any annotations that exist
            [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
            // add just the city annotation
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

            [self gotoDefaultLocation];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)cityAction:(id)sender
{
    [self gotoByAnnotationClass:[SFAnnotation class]];
}

- (IBAction)bridgeAction:(id)sender
{
    // user tapped "Bridge" button in the bottom toolbar
    [self gotoByAnnotationClass:[BridgeAnnotation class]];
}

- (IBAction)teaGardenAction:(id)sender
{
    // user tapped "Tea Garden" button in the bottom toolbar
    [self gotoByAnnotationClass:[CustomAnnotation class]];
}

- (IBAction)allAction:(id)sender
{
    // user tapped "All" button in the bottom toolbar

    // remove any annotations that exist
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

    // add all 3 annotations
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapAnnotations];

    [self gotoDefaultLocation];
}


#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

// user tapped the disclosure button in the bridge callout
//
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // here we illustrate how to detect which annotation type was clicked on for its callout
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation1 = [view annotation];
    if ([annotation1 isKindOfClass:[BridgeAnnotation class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"clicked Golden Gate Bridge annotation");

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            // for iPad, we use a popover
            if (self.bridgePopoverController == nil)
            {
                _bridgePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailViewController];
            }
            [self.bridgePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:control.bounds
                                                          inView:control
                                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                                        animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            // for iPhone we navigate to a detail view controller using UINavigationController
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        }

    }
}





// user tapped the disclosure button in city of San Francisco callout
//
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView2:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // here we illustrate how to detect which annotation type was clicked on for its callout
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation2 = [view annotation];
    if ([annotation2 isKindOfClass:[SFAnnotation class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"clicked City of San Francisco annotation");

        DetailViewController *detailViewController2 = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController2"];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            // for iPad, we use a popover
            if (self.sfPopoverController == nil)
            {
                _sfPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailViewController2];
            }
            [self.sfPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:control.bounds
                                                          inView:control
                                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                                        animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            // for iPhone we navigate to a detail view controller using UINavigationController
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController2 animated:YES];

        }

    }
}








- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *returnedAnnotationView = nil;

    // in case it's the user location, we already have an annotation, so just return nil
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        // handle our three custom annotations
        //
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BridgeAnnotation class]]) // for Golden Gate Bridge
        {
            returnedAnnotationView = [BridgeAnnotation createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapView annotation:annotation];

            // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page or a popover
            //
            // note: when the detail disclosure button is tapped, we respond to it via:
            //       calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method
            //
            // by using "calloutAccessoryControlTapped", it's a convenient way to find out which annotation was tapped
            //
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ((MKPinAnnotationView *)returnedAnnotationView).rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        }






        else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SFAnnotation class]]) // for City of San Francisco
        {
            returnedAnnotationView = [SFAnnotation createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapView annotation:annotation];

            // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page or a popover
            //
            // note: when the detail disclosure button is tapped, we respond to it via:
            //       calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method
            //
            // by using "calloutAccessoryControlTapped", it's a convenient way to find out which annotation was tapped
            //
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ((MKPinAnnotationView *)returnedAnnotationView).rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        }






        else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) // for City of Tea Garden
        {
            returnedAnnotationView = [CustomAnnotation createViewAnnotationForMapView:self.mapView annotation:annotation];

            // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page or a popover
            //
            // note: when the detail disclosure button is tapped, we respond to it via:
            //       calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method
            //
            // by using "calloutAccessoryControlTapped", it's a convenient way to find out which annotation was tapped
            //
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:nil action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ((MKPinAnnotationView *)returnedAnnotationView).rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        }
    }

    return returnedAnnotationView;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with your actual code, and remove your download link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView2:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

will not be called by the map view because it's not named ***exactly*** `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`.

Naming the method `annotationView2` does not automatically associate it with your "second" annotation.  Delegate methods must be named exactly as defined by the protocol (`MKMapViewDelegate` in this case).

You must handle all callout button taps in this one method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

In there, you can check the annotation's class and handle accordingly (like you are already doing with `BridgeAnnotation`).  For example:

```
if ([annotation1 isKindOfClass:[BridgeAnnotation class]])
{
    //code for Bridge annotation...
}
else
if ([annotation1 isKindOfClass:[SFAnnotation class]])
{
    //code for SF annotation...
}
else ...
```